# Zip file cracker python 3 will only use password at end of text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

I have been searching and mucking around for days trying to make a zip cracker in python 3.

I have a text file with my passwords in it called passwords.txt. and each password in on a new line. (no space in between lines)

e.g:

```
password
house
qwerty
```

the script runs ok and will extract the file in my zip. (zip password was qwerty). BUT if I rearrange my list like so:

```
password
qwerty
house
```

the script will not crack the zip. It will work fine with 'qwerty' as the only password in the list and will work if 'qwerty' is the last password in the list. To me its like the script is not terminating after using the correct password. I need a bit of a push in the right direction.

here is my (simple) code: (i'm no expert)

```
import zipfile
with open('passwords.txt') as passwordList:
    myZip = zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip')
    for line in passwordList:
        try:
            myZip.setpassword(pwd=line.encode())
            myZip.extractall()

        except:
            pass

myZip.close()
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I guess ... the lines you read from the file have line ending characters, so they aren't actually the right password. The last line has no line ending character because there are no blank lines after it, so it works when the password is in that position. As the first thing in your loop, above `try`, add: `line = line.strip()` to remove the whitespace/newlines from the beginning/end of line.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `\n` from your `line` variable with `line.strip(b'\n')` and not `line.strip()`, because password may have whitespace around itself.

Also you can pass `pwd` to `extractall` directly.

```
import zipfile

zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip')
output_verbose = 2  # increase that for long password list
with open('passwords.txt', 'rb') as password_list:
    for index, line in enumerate(password_list):
        try:
            pwd = line.strip(b'\n')
            zip_file.extractall(pwd=pwd)
        except RuntimeError:
            if index % output_verbose == 0:
                print('{}. The {} word not matched.'.format(index + 1, pwd))
        else:
            print('{}. Wow ! found the password: {}'.format(index + 1, pwd))
            break

zip_file.close()
```

Demo:

```
1. The b'password' word not matched.
2. Wow ! found the password: b'qwerty'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
justin =  '''
    +=======================================+

    |..........Zip Cracker v 1.........|

    +---------------------------------------+

    |#Author: JUSTIN                    |

    |#Contact: www.fb.com/rootx        |


    +=======================================+

    |..........ZIP Cracker v 1.........|

    +---------------------------------------+
'''

print justin

import zipfile

z1 = raw_input("Enter Your Zip File:")

z = zipfile.ZipFile(z1)

pf1=str(raw_input( "Enter password list: "))

pf=open(pf1,'r')

for x in pf.readlines():

password = x.strip('\n')

try:

    z.extractall(pwd=password)

    print "pass=" +password+ "\n"

    exit(0)

except Exception,e:
   pass
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for posting an answer. Please consider adding context to your code. Also, please format your code correctly. See [this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) for help with formatting